# Android Fragment isn't accepting setcontentview

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I am trying to use fragments to make swiped tabs by tablayouts (one activity with three tabs), I made three Java files for the tree tabs and the corresponding xml files as the below tutorial and it is working and I had the three tabs.  but I stuck now in how to apply any code for any object inside these tabs .. should it be in the tab java file?

if yes, the onCreateView method isn't accepting (findviewbyid) and I tried to add onCreate method but it is not accepting (setContentView)

I also tried to add the code in the main activity class but when I it returns the below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

where should I set my objects and apply my code for any tab?

the tutorial:

http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Edit Adding codes:

Fragment Java Code:

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class DCOGeneralReports extends Fragment {

private DatePicker datePicker;
private Calendar calendar;
private TextView EndDate;
private int year, month, day;
private Button DailyReportGenerate, CustomReportGenerate, StartDateSelect, EndDateSelect;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dco_general_report, container, false);
    TextView StartDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.SDate);
    return view;
}
```

Fragment XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Daily Report"
    android:textColor="#1B5E20"
    android:id="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Press Generate to get DCO Today Report"
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate"
    android:textColor="#1B5E20"
    android:id="@+id/DailyReport"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Custom Report"
    android:textColor="#1B5E20"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/DailyReport"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView6"
    android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Select Start And End Date Then Press Select"
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Start Date: "
    android:id="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="End Date"
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="SDate"
    android:id="@+id/SDate"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView6" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="EDate"
    android:id="@+id/EDate"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
    android:layout_marginStart="143dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Select"
    android:id="@+id/SelectStartDate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/DailyReport" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Select"
    android:id="@+id/SelectEndDate"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SelectStartDate"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/SelectStartDate" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Generate"
    android:textColor="#1B5E20"
    android:id="@+id/CustomReport"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/SelectEndDate"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    />
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can not call setContentView in fragment. You should override onCreateView method in fragment and inflate your layout.

Comment: your xml file is wrong. Use view group like LinearLayout with vertical orientation. and put all your views as child of linear layout.

Comment: add your complete crash log

Comment: I just found the problem, it seems that there is a conflict in IDs with different activity (I changed it ti SDate1 in both codes and it is solved). would you please tell me why my XML is wrong? why is it necessary to make it Linear Layout? I made it Relative one.

Comment: you add layout first time without any view group(without Relative layout), but latter you add right layout.Now your layout is looking Ok

Comment: oooh thanks it is my fault. is the objects IDs must be unique on the app level or only on activity level? as I had no object with the same id in the same activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call setContentView in Fragment. You should override the onCreatView method of fragment and inflate your layout as follows:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View v= inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_2, container, false);

        //to get view like textview, button etc use v.findViewById(yourid)

        TextView textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        return v;
    }
}.
```

Comment: I did the same exactly but I am getting an error (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference)

Answer (score 1):

For a `Fragment` you

- override `onCreateView`
- Inflate a view
- use `findViewById` on the view reference
- return the view

  ```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
      Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
      ...
      return view;
  }
  ```

Comment: I did the same exactly but I am getting an error (java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference)

Comment: You have to make sure that your layout XML contains a widget that has the exact same id as the `findViewById` argument.  When you get a `NullPointerException` on `findViewById`, it usually means that you don't have a view with that id.  You should post both your code and your layout XML in your question.

Comment: I edited it with both codes .. I wish you can find the problem